# How to download a file only if more recently changed in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I usually use `wget` to download files in a Makefile, e.g.:

`my_file:
    wget http://myserver/$@ -O $@.tmp && mv $@.tmp $@`

I first download in a tmp file: in case the transfer is interrupted, the file will be correctly re-download when re-launching the Makefile.

The problem is, with the `-O` option, it is not possible to use the `-N` option to fetch the file only if the remote file is more recent than the local file.

My question is: what is the best way, in a Makefile, to download a file only if the remote file is more recent, and to be robust to transfer interruptions?

Comment: Copy it after fetching it so that `wget` can manage the original file name as it sees fit?

Comment: Well, in that case the name of the target and of the remote file should be different, it's bothersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `cURL` instead of `wget`. My Makefile target becomes:

```
my_file:
    curl -s -S -L -f http://myserver/$@ -z $@ -o $@.tmp && mv -f $@.tmp $@ 2>/dev/null || rm -f $@.tmp $@
```

Explanation:

```
-s: silent, no progress bar displayed
-S: if silent, shows error message on fail
-L: in case of redirection, follow it and redo the request; this is necessary to correctly get modification date
-f: in case of error do not display the document returned
-z my_local_file: download remote file only if last modification date more recent that modification date of 'my_local_file'
-o filename: store downloaded file into 'filename'
```

- on success, move temp file to final location (`&& mv -f $@.tmp $@`)
- stderr of `mv` redirected to `/dev/null` in case the file was not redownloaded, so that the temp file does not exist (`&& mv -f $@.tmp $@ 2> /dev/null`)
- in case of error, `rm` temp file and final file (`|| rm -f $@.tmp $@`)